# C++ Files and Folders access View and Control

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, file

two quick Qs:
1. Is it possible to write a program which keep record of folders and files a User access to? (i.e. browse)
2. and Control his/her access? (deny access to some of folders, programs, file and ...)

I know about file system security and stuff but I meant here is at first a monitoring system which keeps record of all users file system activity on PC and *then* the possiblity to control it.

tnx

Comment: Of course these things are possible. But what operating system?

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in tools in Windows?

Comment: at least I don't know any tools in Windows for monitoring which files ad folders a User viewed.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399

Comment: oh, thanks, but this only works on NTFS fs. I think that it is possible programmatic, it would be global. any programmatic solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DACL to control access. Use an SACL to monitor access.

If you really want to know everything they *look* at (including things like USB drives that won't have an ACLs assigned) you'll probably need to use a hook on WH_SHELL to get notified about their use of the shell.

You *could* also use something like the Detours library to hook their shell's use of things like FindFirstFile, FindNextFile, CreateFile, and CreateProcess. When they create a process, you'd then hook *it's* use of FindFirstFile, FindNextFile, etc., to keep track of what they do in those programs, and so on.

If you really want something that's difficult to get around, however, you'd probably just about have to supply your own shell for them to use.